# Парсинг отзывов из Яндекс Карты и Google Place

Tags: php, html, парсер, api, yandex-maps-api

Хочу решить задачу с копированием отзывов в мой WP сайт из google place или яндекс карты. но там по умолчанию выводится 10 отзывов.
дальше они както по ajax загружаются при пролистывании. какими средствами решить проблему?
номера телефонов, адреса я копирую с помощью Simple Php dom parser. а тут как быть? кнопка "показать больше отзывов" имеет такой код:

```
<div class="reviews__need-more">
    <button class="button button_theme_islands button_size_xl button__control i-bem button_js_inited" role="button" type="button" data-bem="{&quot;button&quot;:{}}">
        <span class="button__text">Показать больше отзывов</span>
    </button> 
</div>
```

https://yandex.ru/maps/org/mriya_resort_spa/1303073708/ - пример страницы с отзывами

Comment: Отлавливаете AJAX-запрос и парсите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для вашего примера:
В ajax запросы подгружаются через POST:

```
url: https://yandex.ru/maps/org/api/review/get
data: {"oid":"1303073708","page":2,"csrfToken":"****"}
```

Как видим, в json содержится id нужного объекта, номер страницы отзывов, и личный csrfToken, который можно найти в исходном коде страницы. В ответ приходит HTML с комментариями.

Можете посмотреть, как проходит запрос, открыв в браузере инструменты анализа (F12) -> вкладка "network" (или "сеть"). При клике на кнопку увидите, что отправился новый запрос, и можете посмотреть информацию о нём.